# Is it normal for key lime pie filling to be bubbly like water and overflow while baking?

Tags: baking, pie, lime

I made mini lime pie in muffin tin and after a while, the filling is boiling like water and overflows. I bake it in 180c (350f-ish) and after 30 minutes they don't seem to ser properly. Shoulf I bake it longer?

Comment: it would help if you [edit]ed the question to add the full recipe you're following

Comment: Hi - may you tell us a little more in what you used in your "custard" key lime pie filling? Usually, it is simple, condense milk - egg yolks and lime juice? The filling is generally pretty thick, to begin with, so any extra info would be helpful to provide an answer.

Comment: How did you mix the filling?  If you whipped air into it, they might come out when baked which will look like boiling.  Slamming the tin against the counter a few times before cooking might help get out large bubbles before baking, but doesn’t always help with the smaller ones

Answer (score 3):

If you are following a recipe for **a full-sized pie** and baking it **in muffin tins,** the time will need to be adjusted *(less time.)*

Sounds like you went *far past* the point you actually want to be making the custard and just boiled it.